# How to deploy Front & Back node.js on the same Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

To be able to run my app, I need to run these 2 command in 2 different terminal :

1. cd app && npm install & npm start
2. cd api && npm install & npm start

I basically launch the front (app) and the back (api).
I want to deploy that on Heroku, but using the free plan.

Is there a way to do that? Do I need to create a package.json file on the root folder? If yes what should be inside? 
Whatever I write, it seems to run only the front and never the back.

Many thanks!

Comment: The way I've approached this is to build the front end, and serve the resulting HTML/JS/CSS from the backend. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/cyf-app-starter for a starting point.

Comment: Which front-end framework/library are you using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it would mean to re-write all my code. I want to use it like this.

Comment: @ShamsNahid I am using react/redux

Comment: Well then the short answer is that you can't, a Heroku app will only bind a single port.

Comment: @jonrsharpe would something like this will work then?
web: npm install --prefix app && npm start --prefix app
server: npm install --prefix api && npm start --prefix api

Comment: How *would* that solve the problem I described?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the front-end and then serve it from the server end.

Whatever front-end framework you are using, make sure the build file is kept in the server static directory. Then make a route to load the build file (in most cases index.html).

Your steps might be

- First, build the production-ready front-end (in most cases, it will generate the index.html in a distribution directory).
- Put the distribution directory in your server public or static directory.
- Make route in your server end and server the static file (mainly the index.html)
- Now you are ready to go, put the node server to heroku.

  For example, your final route might be

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
          res.sendFile("static index.html file path");
  })

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my app works perfectly in local as it is. I don't want to change the all infrastructure of my app (for now) but just trying to trick heroku to run the front and the back from the same app.